# PHP: Shouldn´t $array[] = $x; add a new array item?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this script where I generate dynamically with javascript a bunch of text inputs.

After that I want to iterate between then in order to sum it´s contents and do a calculation.

The result of each iteration should be added to the end of an array. I don´t know why, but the array contents seems to be replaced every time the loop starts again, and it should add the new element created by the loop instead. But the only content it takes is the first one, and not the last one added.

### Here´s the sample,

```
  $totalCeldas = strip_tags($_POST['totalCeldas']);
  $mesesTotales = array();
  for ($vuelta=1; $vuelta<$totalCeldas; $vuelta++) {     
    $mes = 'mes'.$vuelta;
    $anio = 'yr'.$vuelta;
    $exp = 'exp'.$vuelta;

    $valorMes = strip_tags($_POST[$mes]);
    $valorAnio = strip_tags($_POST[$anio]);
    $x = (($tYear - $valorAnio ) * 12) + ($tMonth- $valorMes);
    $mesesTotales[] = $x;
    echo '$valorAnio '.$valorAnio.'<br>';
    echo '$valorMes '.$valorMes.'<br>';
    //I´ve tried printing out each iteration in order to get to the problem, but it only prints out the first value.
    foreach($mesesTotales as $valor){
    echo 'El valor es '.$valor.'<br>';
    }
```

I´ve also tried [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), with the same result: It grabs only the result in the first iteration.

### This is how the fields gets generated in Javascript:

```
function generarTabla1() {
  var cant = document.forms["generar-tabla"]["cantMeses"].value;
  if (cant && !isNaN(cant)) { 
    for ($i=0; $i<cant; $i++) { 
      var e = 0;
      var celdaMes = " Mes <input style='width:5%;' type='text' name='mes"+($i+1)+"'> ";
      var celdaYr = " Año <input style='width:8%;' type='text' name='yr"+($i+1)+"'> ";
      var celdaExp = " Expensa $<input style='width:15%;' type='text' name='exp"+($i+1)+"'>                      
       <br>";
      $('#output').append(celdaMes, celdaYr, celdaExp); //agregamos las celdas necesarias
    }
```

Comment: Try do simple loop without any data, to check `[]` execution.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just pushing the same value over and over again? Your `$x` seems to not change with each iteration of the loop

Comment: Works fine more me: http://codepad.org/2TmnhAR2. Must be a problem with your loop.

Comment: Hmmm, but $x is the result of a calculation, and in each iteration its contents should change because it does change the value of $valorAnio and $valorMes...

Comment: But $_POST[$mes] should change ($mes = 'mes'.$vuelta;): $mes is "mes1", and the "mes2" in the next loop, etc... and those  $_POST['mes1'], $_POST['mes2'], etc, are the contents of the different form inputs...

Comment: @xbonez `$x` not changing but it HAVE to be added to the end of the array `$mesesTotales` because of `[]`... Isn't it?

Comment: What does your post array/html look like?

Comment: I´ve edited the question in order to show the JS that does create the fields

Comment: Where is $totalCeldas set?

Comment: sorry, forgot to post that line: $totalCeldas is right before the for loop.

Comment: [code in English](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather answer this than deleting the question, in case someone else have the same silly issue:
Yes, the for loop has an issue: It should say lees or equal than, and not only less than.

So this:

```
  for ($vuelta=1; $vuelta<$totalCeldas; $vuelta++) {
```

Changed for this:

```
  for ($vuelta=1; $vuelta<=$totalCeldas; $vuelta++) {
```

worked.

I know, it´s silly, but I didn´t feel that was right to delete the question or let it go unanswered.